# Send AJAX request to .aspx page and return JSON

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, web-services, webforms

I know that it is possible to send an AJAX request to an `.asmx` page. And I also know that an `.asmx` page handles an AJAX request via a web method.

Is it also possible to send an AJAX request to an `.aspx` page? If so, does an `.aspx` page also handle an AJAX request via a web method? Note that I would like to return a JSON response from the `.aspx` page. Is this possible?

Comment: here is a link which may help you http://blog.devarchive.net/2007/12/calling-page-methods-from-javascript.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define web methods in the code-behind of your `.aspx` page and then call them:

```cs
[WebMethod]
public static string doSomething(int id)
{
    ...
    return "hello";
}
```

And then, to call a web method in your jQuery code:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "YourPage.aspx/doSomething",
    data: "{'id':'1'}",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        var returnedstring = data.d;
        var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data.d);//if you want your data in json
    }
});
```

[Here](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) is a good link to get started.

Answer (score 2):

if i understood question correctly, Aspx is same as HTML. It will be rendered as HTML. but only difference is Server Side and Controls retaining the states with state mechanism.

so you can do  jquery `$.ajax()` function.

```
$.ajax({
     url: UrlToGetData,
     dataType:'json',
     success:function(data){
             //do some thing with data. 
           }
});
```

or if you want to write out json value to the response, then use `Response.ContentType`
first use any Javascript serializer(JSON.NET) , then set the contentType like this.

```
Response.ContentType="application/json";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "(aspx page name/method to be called from the aspx.cs page)",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $.toJSON(jsonData),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                 //TO DO after success
        }
});
```

Try the above code