# Read Post Data With C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, post

I'm Using the Jquery Ajax Function to send data from an html page, & I'm reading it at the backend with C#.

When I used Get, the data were sent successfully, but when I switched to Post, the data value is null at the backend.

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="AddData();>
<input type="submit"value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function AddData() {
            var RData = GetRData();
            var postData = { 'Function': "AddData", 'RData': JSON.stringify(RData) };
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Services/GetRData.aspx",
                data: postData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
                success: function (result) { 
                AddClubCallBackFunction(result) },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert('Sorry, an error occured while adding your Data!');
                }
            });
        }
```

C#:

```
string FunctionName =Request["Function"]; //null
string RData = Request.Form["RData"]; //null
```

So, what am I doing wrong & how can I fix it ?

**Update:**

I just removed

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

and it worked.

Comment: Why do you submit to an ASPX page? It would be so much easier to just create a web service (WCF or ASMX), wouldn't it?

Comment: result.d may do the trick...

Comment: Even submitting to aspx page is easier. Still cannot understand how are you trying it. Are you using any [WebMethod] on your aspx code behind?

Comment: @ZedBee what do you mean ?

Comment: @writeToBhuwan Where should I write it ?

Comment: AddClubCallBackFunction(result.d)

Comment: You must first cancel the form submission: `<form onsubmit="AddData(); return false;">` otherwise the data will be sent by the form submit itself and the AJAX will be lost.

Comment: @SanaJoseph http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: @SanaJoseph http://stackoverflow.com/a/14624192/1099235

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the above code is *exactly* what you are executing, there does appear to be a typo:

```
var Data = GetRData();
var postData = { 'Function': "AddData", 'RData': JSON.stringify(RData) };
```

Your variable is `Data` but your calling `JSON.Stringify` on `RData` which hasn't been declared (hence null property).

**Update**

Based on your last comment I would say it's a JSON formatting issue. This can generally happen when you attempt to manually construct JSON objects which you are *partly* doing in your solution. I would change your code to:

```
var rdata = GetRData();
var postData = { Function: 'AddData', RData: JSON.stringify(rdata) };
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    ...
});
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I fixed it, but it's still not working. 
The "function is not correctly read too.

Comment: @SanaJoseph so given the change made, when you read the property on the server side it's still `null`? It's worth verifying that the data in your `RData` can actually be converted to JSON successfully e.g. output your `postData` to the console and verify it against a [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Yes, nothing is returned, just null.

Comment: @SanaJoseph "*nothing is returned*" - are you talking about nothing is returned **from** the server or nothing is **sent** to the server? You need to be a bit more clear in what your saying as these are 2 completely different problems.

Comment: "Something" is sent . I even alerted the RData & became sure of what's sent in it. But at the aspx page, Request["RData"]'s value is null & Request["Function"] is null too.

Comment: @SanaJoseph that tells me that your JSON is invalid as the server is unable to parse it. See my update.

Comment: I don't get it, how can the Json be invalid ? How can I send it then ?

Comment: @SanaJoseph "*how can the JSON be invalid?*" - pretty easily actually and not always immediately obvious. You aren't actually passing `JSON` to the server with the way your sending it, your passing a javascript object (which is completely different). You need to call `stringify` on the `postData` parameter itself.

Comment: But when I changed it to:  data: JSON.stringify(postData). The issue was still not fix, is there another method to send the data ?

Comment: @SanaJoseph Could you post an example of the JSON you are sending to the server? Your server is expecting JSON but isn't getting valid JSON so is unable to parse it. For example, change your code to be: `data: JSON.stringify({ Function: 'MyFunc', RData: 'test' }),` - it should work fine. My guess is your `GetRData` isn't actually returning valid JSON.

Comment: That's what I send :  RData = {"Name": "Data Club", "Goal": "Being A True developer","Activities": "Practicing All Stuff"};

Comment: @SanaJoseph could you post the full `postData` data that is being sent? That section of JSON is valid, however, that's just a portion of it.

Comment: I tried :  data: JSON.stringify({ "Function": 'MyFunc', "Club": 'test' }),

& 

 data: JSON.stringify({ Function: 'MyFunc', Club: 'test' }),

but both didn't work.

Comment: So if you change the content-type to be `application/json` does it work? You are telling the server your sending JSONP but really your just sending JSON. For JSONP, you generally append a `callback` parameter to the URL e.g. `/Services/GetRData.aspx?callback=AddData`