# JavaScript code calling codebehind function only one time

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have a JavaScript function which is not calling a function in codebehind more than once. I have debugged it and I can confirm that it is not calling more than once. Is it something that I am missing?

JavaScript code:

```
function loader() {
            for(var i=0;i<<%=array1.Length%>;i++)
            {<%increment();%>;
             alert(<%=counter%>);
            }

        }
```

codebehind function:

```
public int counter = -1;
       public void increment()
       { counter++; }
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RonWilliams says, that code is *only* executed at the begining, when the `aspx` is rendering, and not anymore.

The only way the code is executed in the form you write it, is for example inside a `asp:Repeater` or inside a `asp:TemplateField` in a `GridView`.

If you want to call a server-side functions try with [AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14624192/4773983) or with [Page Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30083658/4773983)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really intertwine your client-side Javascript code and your server-side C# code like this. Basically, once the rendering has been done on your page, you aren't really going to access the server until either a `PostBack` has occurred or your use AJAX to call an exposed `WebMethod`.

It'll call it once when the page initially renders, otherwise, you would need to use one of the other techniques.

**`WebMethod` Approach**

You could accomplish this as I mentioned earlier by taking advantage of a `WebMethod`, which would involve you creating a method in your code-behind that looks something like this :

```
[WebMethod]
public static void IncrementCounter()
{
     // Since you want to return the incremented value, use ++counter
     return ++counter;
}
```

And then you would need to add a reference in your ASPX page to the jQuery library, which will be used to handle performing AJAX calls to access this server-side method :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script>
    // This will ensure that your jQuery code is ready to run
    $(function(){
          // When the page is ready, call your loading function
          loader();
    });

    function loader() {
        for(var i=0; i< <%=array1.Length%>; i++){
            // This will call your WebMethod
            $.post('YourPage.aspx/IncrementCounter', function(count){
                  // count will contain the counter value
                  alert(count);
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i understand that this is the issue, but why is such functionality even available, if it can't be put to use ? is there any workaround other than what you have mentioned with the existing code i have, help is really appreciated !

Comment: I've just edited my response to include a basic example of how to handle calling your server-side code via a Web Method, which hopefully helps you out.